# Need help to figure why my array its not saving an input?

Tags: c++

so this is a ship's database and my problem is that I have to check if the user enter an integer, but when the program saves registry to the array and I show the result the registry variable where the user puts the number its an scramble of numbers

```
int tester1 = 0; 
cout << "What is the registry of the ship?: ";
            cout << " >>";



            if (cin >> tester1)
            {
            tester1 >> array[counter].registry;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            }

            else
            {
                while (!(cin >> tester1))
                {
                    cout << "Please enter an integer!!" << endl;
                    cout << " >>";
                    cin >> tester1;
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                }


            }
```

Comment: `tester1 >> array[counter].registry;` What's that? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tester1 grabs the user input and checks if is an int so if is an int then tester1 its saved into the array by using

Comment: tester1 >> array[counter].registry;

Comment: Why is it that nobody wanna help me !!

Comment: Without an MCVE, I am finding it hard to understand what you are asking. Since I don't understand what you are asking, I can't give you any useful answer. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show your console input/output. It is not that easy to understand what a "scramble of numbers" means.

Comment: hey guys thanks I figure it out Instead of

Comment: tester1 >> array[counter].registry; it should been array[counter].registry;= tester1;

Comment: Hey guys if your switch statement its a char how can you check that user is inputting one char to allow switch to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>tester1; 
while(!cin) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter an integer!!" << endl;
    cout << " >>";
    cin>>tester1;
}
array[counter].registry=tester1;
```

Comment: if your switch statement its a char how can you check that user is inputting one char to allow switch to happen

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining what you are doing and why.

Comment: @YusmePradera `var_char=getchar(); // No matter how many characters are inputted, only the first one is recorded`